# Змейка не двигается по оси Y

Tags: python, pygame

Это код змейки. Она двигаеться влево/вправо,но не двигаеться вверх/вниз
Помогите понять почему.

Код программы:

```
import pygame
from random import randrange
pygame.init()

snake_size = 20
black = (0, 0, 0)
green = (0, 200, 0)

x_snake_pos = 350
y_snake_pos = 350

x_motion = 0
y_motion = 0

snake_list = list()

sc = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 700))
pygame.display.set_caption("змейка")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    
run = True
while run:

        sc.fill(black)

        for i in pygame.event.get() :
        
                if i.type == pygame.QUIT :
                        run = False
            
                if i.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            
                        if i.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                                x_motion = -snake_size
                                y_motoin = 0                    
 
                        elif i.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                                x_motion = snake_size
                                y_motoin = 0
                
                        if i.key == pygame.K_UP:
                                x_motion = 0
                                y_motoin = snake_size

                        elif i.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                                x_motion = 0
                                y_motoin = -snake_size

        x_snake_pos += x_motion
        y_snake_pos += y_motion

        snake_head_pos = []
        snake_head_pos.append(x_snake_pos)
        snake_head_pos.append(y_snake_pos)

        snake_list.append(snake_head_pos)

        for pos in snake_list:
                pygame.draw.rect(sc, green, (pos[0], pos[1], snake_size, snake_size))

        if len(snake_list) > 10:
                del (snake_list[0])

        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(10)
    
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переменная y_motion была названа с ошибкой:y_motoin.

```
import pygame
from random import randrange
pygame.init()

snake_size = 20
black = (0, 0, 0)
green = (0, 200, 0)

x_snake_pos = 350
y_snake_pos = 350

x_motion = 0
y_motion = 0

snake_list = list()

sc = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 700))
pygame.display.set_caption("змейка")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    
run = True
while run:

        sc.fill(black)

        for i in pygame.event.get() :
        
                if i.type == pygame.QUIT :
                        run = False
            
                if i.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            
                        if i.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                                x_motion = -snake_size
                                y_motion = 0                    
 
                        elif i.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                                x_motion = snake_size
                                y_motion = 0
                
                        if i.key == pygame.K_UP:
                                x_motion = 0
                                y_motion = snake_size
                                   
                        elif i.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                                x_motion = 0
                                y_motion = -snake_size

        x_snake_pos += x_motion
        y_snake_pos += y_motion

        snake_head_pos = []
        snake_head_pos.append(x_snake_pos)
        snake_head_pos.append(y_snake_pos)

        snake_list.append(snake_head_pos)

        for pos in snake_list:
                pygame.draw.rect(sc, green, (pos[0], pos[1], snake_size, snake_size))

        if len(snake_list) > 10:
                del (snake_list[0])

        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(10)
    
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: спасибо большое. при запуске не жаловалось, что такой переменной нет, вот я и не обратил внимания, а оказалось, что просто я не очень внимательный.

Comment: @АлёшаБакулин В python компилятор будет жаловатся на необьявленую переменную только если вы используете ее как операнд после "="

Comment: спасибо. я учту это, когда будет подобная проблема